# relating has_and_belongs_to_many table to a fourth table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

Thanks for the help first of all.

I have **User**(table) and has_and_belongs_to_many **Products**(table) with a joining table **UserJoinProducts**. I have this and works.

My problem is..

I want to create a table where **Users** have a records when they CheckIn or Out a **Product** and also have record of each Iteration.

I want user to have a record for each time they check_in or out the same product.

> ### |user|produ| _date--  |in |
>
> ### |bob | eggs    |1/1/2016| X |
>
> ### |bob | Coke    |1/1/2016| X |
>
> ### |bob | eggs    |1/5/2016| -- |
>
> ### |bob |  Coke   |1/7/2016| -- |
>
> ### |bob | eggs    |1/9/2016| X |

[Click here for A sad example of my table ;) lol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aU8n.png)

Thanks Again For your Help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do I relate this fourth table to my other tables so I can keep record of my user check in and outs keeping track of the user and product

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it this way. You're probably better off using `has_many through`  relation for `User` and `Product` models.

And then use the through table to store the `check_in` or `check_out` `datetime` fields. So this way you'll have a model for your joining table to access these fields.

It's always recommended to use `has_many through` as whenever you use `has_and_belongs_to_many`, most of the time you end up in a similar situation, and would want to change the architecture.

Comment: how do I relate this fourth table to my other tables so I can keep record of my user check in and outs keeping track of the user and product

Comment: @JuanLopez that's what i meant, i wouldn't do as you are suggesting, having a fourth table to store that info. That just is not the right way to go according to me.